# Regex to match specific last path part of url

Tags: regex

For redirect purposes, I'm trying to match the last part of a path in a url. I want to match any url that ends with "/serve", whether or not a query string is present or not.

I have tried numerous Regex patterns but the following one seems to work, but it's the presence of a query string that breaks the match:

Pattern I've tried:

`\/([a-z0-9_-]*\/serve[\/]?)$`

Examples of test strings that should match:

```
https://test.com/serve
https://test.com/serve/?param=1
https://test.com/serve/
http://test.com/serve
```

Examples of test strings that should NOT match:

```
https://test.com/serve/ways-to-serve
https://test.com/serve/ways-to-serve?param=1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In future please post the actual code you have used, since with regexes different languages use different flavours and have different capabilities for processing regular expressions. Or at least tick the flag for the language you are trying to use. This will also make it easier for other users who are stuck with the same problem to know the solution is likely to work for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```js
\/([^\/]+\/serve\/?)(?:$|\?)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vQucsy/1).

*Details*:

- `\/` - a `/` char
- `([^\/]+\/serve\/?)` - Capturing group 1: one or more chars other than a `/` char, then a `/serve`, an optional `/` char
- `(?:$|\?)` - a non-capturing group matching end of string or a `?` char.

See the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5C%2F(%5B%5E%5C%2F%5D%2B%5C%2Fserve%5C%2F%3F)(%3F%3A%24%7C%5C%3F)):

[image]